# set exclude form fields

Tags: python, django, forms

i have problem by insert into form field.

this is comment models.py:

```
class UserComment(models.Model):
comment_id=              models.AutoField(primary_key=True)
comment_on_product_id=   models.ForeignKey(Post) 
user_name=               models.CharField(max_length=50)
comment_text=            models.TextField()
comment_timestamp=       models.TimeField(auto_now_add=True,auto_now=True)
```

and my forms.py :

```
class UserCommentForm(forms.ModelForm):
class Meta:
    model=UserComment
    exclude=['comment_on_product_id',]
```

and what should users see:
[image]

as you see comment_on_product_id should not appear on page but i have to insert a value in that field.
in views i code like this :
  .
  .
  .

```
form=UserCommentForm(request.POST or None)
if form.is_valid():
    form.Meta.model.comment_on_product_id= selected_object.product_id
    save_it=form.save(commit=False)
    save_it.save()
```

but it looks form.Meta.model.comment_on_product_id= selected_object.product_id dosent work.
error :
 Failing row contains (112, **null**, usernaem, comment text, 18:33:39.848621).

why it is null ? and how i should set it ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Access the instance on the form, not the Meta class.

```
form=UserCommentForm(request.POST or None)
if form.is_valid():
    form.instance.comment_on_product_id= selected_object.product_id
    save_it=form.save(commit=False)
    save_it.save()
```

Comment: thanks. but dosent work. error :                                   Cannot assign "2": "UserComment.comment_on_product_id" must be a "Store" instance. "2" is current product_id

Comment: Change the name ```comment_on_product_id``` on the model to ```comment_on_product```. Then keep the view logic I wrote the same. Otherwise you'll need to change ```form.instance.comment_on_product_id``` to ```form.instance.comment_on_product_id_id```

Comment: comment_on_product_id_id -> what is the second _id  ?

Comment: It's the field on the model that represents the actual pk of the instance the FK is referencing. That's why you should never name a FK field something_id.